# Python.Comparing numbers in 2 lists and finding max

Tags: python, list, function, max

I have 2 lists with elements like:

```
list1=[2,54,31,6,42]
list2=[4,98,43,3,2]
```

I want a def that compares the numbers and returns a 3rd list with the biggest one.

In this example the 3rd list would be:

```
list3=[4,98,43,6,42]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple `def`/function to `zip()` the two lists and then get `max()` and store it into a new list3 and returned:

```
list1=[2,54,31,6,42]
list2=[4,98,43,3,2]

def function(list1,list2): #def returns 3rd list 
    list3 = [max(value) for value in zip(list1, list2)]
    return list3
print(function(list1,list2)) # call def named function to print
```

Output:

```
[4, 98, 43, 6, 42]
```

Answer (score 12):

Use `map()` function:

```
In [4]: list(map(max, list1, list2))
Out[4]: [4, 98, 43, 6, 42]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use list comprehension with `max` function.

```
>>> list1=[2,54,31,6,42];list2=[4,98,43,3,2]
>>> [max(i) for i in zip(list1,list2)]
[4, 98, 43, 6, 42]
>>>
```